# Organizing Fragments and ViewPagers

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm currently designing an android app and tried several kinds of general setups, each seeming to have it's downsides.

The app generally consists of three screens (A, B, C), each of those has a list. On list selection it should change to a detail view (A1, A2, A3).
I want each detail view to be swipeable back to it's list.

All I'm sure about is that I have three buttons in the action bar which let the user switch between A, B and C.

Beyond that I tried those setups:

1. The whole layout is **one ViewPager with six fragments**. 
   *Downside: I have to implement the logic "when and where to swiping is allowed" myself - seemed wrong to me*
2. The layout consists of **three fragments, each containing a Viewpager** with two fragments. The Viewpager-Fragments are replaced on Actionbutton-Clicks

   *Downside: I have to forward all State changes to the inner fragments*
3. The layout consists of **one Viewpager that gets its Adapter replaced** whenever an actionButton is clicked and thus always only has two Fragments at a time

   *Downside: Fragments are often destroyed and recreated*

I hope I made my problem clear.
What general design would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having fragment with viewpager that would show three fragments with lists. Now, on list item select, I would replace this fragment with item details. When user want to swipe back, i would add custom gesture handling that would call onBack. I would argue if such gesture handling is good design but I'm guessing that you simply need to mimic IOS behaviour (which probably most of us have to do too damn often)

Comment: Well I don't want to swipe inbetween lists (A, B, C) but only from a detail view back to its list, so having a viewpager with only the lists in it would make no sense for me.

Comment: Ok, that changes the idea slightly but what will you show to the user after swipe before selecting any list item?

Comment: There's no swipe before list selection, only after it to go back to the list. But as this confuses you I might put more thoughts in it as I should stick to user expectations.

Comment: I think I got the idea now. Unfortunately, now you have a problem of allowing list swipe before any selection is made. You can solve it by forcing items count equal zero but you will end up with animation glitter, as fragment manager didn't have the time to inflate next (detail) fragment before. I don't think there is a good solution to this problem.